# How to set UIRefreshControl spinner size programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to set spinner size programatically as in code below but I can't get it to be small size.

With activity indicator we have two sizes; Large and normal one. I'm using smaller one for activity indicators in my app. I want to set the normal size (smaller one) for refresh control as well. How to do it? 20x20 is the size of small size activity indicator.

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    // This doesn't work     
    // refreshControl.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

    // This doesn't give exact 20x20
    refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    refreshControl.tintColor = .red
    return refreshControl
}()
```

Comment: Your code is working for me in terms of resizing the refreshControl.  Remember that you are transforming the entire refreshControl view with CGAffineTransform not just the ActivityIndicator.

Comment: Code works but I'm not getting exact size I want which is 20x20. I'm not sure what's the default size of spinner for refresh control.

Comment: I just want to resize spinner, is it possible?

Comment: 0.75 should give you 15 pts so 87.5% should give you 20x20.  If this doesn't work create a custom pull to refresh control.